# Angular Routing - Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build an application with Angular but I've run into an error that I'm unsure how to resolve.  It seems to have something to do with the routing that I have set up.

As soon as the page loads it is forced by the routing to go to the first view, which is what I want it to do, but it is throwing a weird error...

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/ng/areq?p0=LoginController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)

The best way I could get your hands on my code is to load it into GitHub.  You can find my repository here...

https://github.com/JosephEricDavis/TimeTrack

It's pretty simple and strait forward so far.  Not a lot of code to dig through yet.  Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if [`Index.cshtml`](https://github.com/JosephEricDavis/TimeTrack/blob/master/TimeTrack/Views/Home/Index.cshtml) is the placeholder page for the Angular portion of your application, you've not explicitly included the JS files for your controllers. I only see the include for `App.js`. It's probably why Angular is complaining about `LoginController` being undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's pretty embarrassing.  As miqid mentioned in the comment, I had forgotten to include script tag references to my controller files.